# Log file for Redis on Windows

Tags: windows, redis

We run the windows port of Redis. At times it stops accepting connections and I'd like to troubleshoot the issue. It seems that there is no .log file like there is in the Linux version.  I have looked in the directory where it's running, but I can't find it.

Does anyone know where I can find the log file and/or turn on logging?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind.  I should have looked in the redis.window.conf file.  There are options for logging to the stdout and the event log.